# Disable "Advanced Printing Features" permanently

Tags: linux, windows, printing, hp-laserjet

How can I disable the "Advanced Printing Features" option (in Windows, go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers, right click the printer, go to Printer Preferences -> Advanced)?

When I disable it and click accept, and then open the property pages again, it appears Enabled again.

Why is this happening?

My machine is Windows 7 x64. The printer is a HP Laserjet 1012 and it is installed on a remote Linux machine.

Comment: Using Samba/SMB/CIFS share or socket?

Comment: @Braiam You mean on the Linux side? I'm not sure. I can tell you settings on my windows computer, but I don't have much access to the linux computer. But shouldn't this be an issue with my computer only?

Comment: It could be a faulty driver on the Linux side if it's SMB. If it's PPC or other direct printing method then windows is at fault.

Comment: @Braiam How can I check if the issue is in my Windows PC and fix it?